# User Cache and User Property GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a google app script question. Below are the links for cache and properties functions.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service#getUserCache()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties

It says there is a function such as getUserCache for Cache and getUserProperty. However, how does the script determine the specific user for it? Meaning, how can more than 1 user access the same script if it is deployed? Also, how can you allow more than one user to use the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how does the script determine the specific user for it? : **Based on the user email id**

how can more than 1 user access the same script if it is deployed? : **Using the web app link**

how can you allow more than one user to use the script? : **By sharing the web app link**

Comment: Oh i see i see, because i realised i deployed it as a telegram bot but if i did that whoever uses that bot will become the user

Comment: Hi Umair, so basically if this is the link for deployment, https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfsdasfewf/exec , by sending this link to everyone they will become a new user and userCache will be different?

Comment: Yes, and make sure you have deployed the app with settings "Execute the app as : User accessing the app"